# Is there a way to enforce unique slugs across categories, tags and posts?

Tags: slug

Digging through various sources including documentation from WordPress, my understanding is that uniqueness of slugs are limited to their respective domains. For example, you can't have duplicate categories with the same slug. This applies to tags and posts too.

I'm however able to have the same slug across categories, tags and posts. For example, I can have a category with the slug 'wordpress' as I can a post with the same slug.

Is there a way to enforce unique slugs globally? This would mean that if I create a category that has the slug of 'WordPress' and if I attempt to create a post with the same slug, it appends a suffix e.g. -2